# Objectify with appengine, 400 Bad Request. No class was registered

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm using objectify + app engine endpoints in order to save data in the cloud.
I have create my "point" entity (it's a point in google maps) with objectify:

```
package com.example.Javier.WH.backend;

import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.type.LatLng;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class Point {

@Id
String id;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;
Double ratius;
String date;
String title;
String description;

public Point(){}

public Point(Double la, Double lo,String stitle){
    latitude = la;
    longitude = lo;
    title = stitle;
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Double getRatius() {
    return ratius;
}

public void setRatius(Double ratius) {
    this.ratius = ratius;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

and this is my "pointEndpoint" class:

```
    package com.example.Javier.WH.backend;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Nullable;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.ConflictException;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.NotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIterator;
import com.googlecode.objectify.cmd.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

@Api(
        name = "pointEndpoint",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "backend.WH.Javier.example.com",
                ownerName = "backend.WH.Javier.example.com",
                packagePath = "")
    )
public class PointEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PointEndpoint.class.getName());

    public PointEndpoint(){}

    @ApiMethod(name = "listPoints")
    public CollectionResponse<Point> listPoints(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString){

        Query<Point> query = ofy().load().type(Point.class);
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != ""){
            query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString));
        }
        List<Point> records = new ArrayList<Point>();
        QueryResultIterator<Point> iterator = query.iterator();
        int num = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            records.add(iterator.next());
        }
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            Cursor cursor = iterator.getCursor();
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();
            }
        }
        return CollectionResponse.<Point>builder().setItems(records).setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "insertPoint")
    public Point insertPoint(Point point) throws ConflictException{
        if(point.getId() != null){
            if(findRecord(point.getId()) != null){
                throw new ConflictException("Object already exists");
            }
        }
        ofy().save().entity(point).now();
        return point;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "insertString")
    public Point insertString(@Named("string") String s) throws ConflictException{
        Point point = new Point(49.500087,7.829500,s);
        if(point.getId() != null) {
            if (findRecord(point.getId()) != null) {
                throw new ConflictException("Object already exists");
            }
        }
        ofy().save().entity(point).now();
        return point;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "updatePoint")
    public Point updatePoint(Point point) throws NotFoundException{
        if(findRecord(point.getId()) == null){
            throw new NotFoundException(("Point record does not exist"));
        }
        ofy().save().entity(point).now();
        return point;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "removePoint")
    public void removeQuote(@Named("id") String id) throws NotFoundException{
        Point record = findRecord(id);
        if(record == null){
            throw new NotFoundException("Point record does not exist");
        }
        ofy().delete().entity(record).now();
    }

    private Point findRecord(String id){
        return ofy().load().type(Point.class).id(id).now();
    }

}
```

the "ofyService" class:

```
    package com.example.Javier.WH.backend;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class OfyService {

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Point.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(MyEndpoint.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy(){
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory(){
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
    def appEmail = "WHATEVER@DOMAIN.com"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.34'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
            email = "${appEmail}"
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

and finally the web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.Javier.WH.backend.MyEndpoint, com.example.Javier.WH.backend.PointEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I don't know from where the error comes. the request seems fine

[image]

but the error always appears

[image]

Comment: remove `import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;` and import & use your own `OfyService` which registers the classes. Your code is currently completely unused.

Answer (score 0):

In your OfyService class you have

```
ObjectifyService.register(Point.class);
ObjectifyService.register(MyEndpoint.class);
```

`MyEndpoint.class` sounds like it is annotated with `@Api` and not with Objectify's `@Entity`. Therefor I assume that you get an exception during application startup or when the static constructor of `OfyService` is executed. This exceptions prevents any entities from being registered thus your actual entity is not registered with Objectify either.
The simple solution here is to not try and register an `@Api` with Objectify. Only register classes that are `@Entity`-annotated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Javier.WH.backend.OfyService </listener-class>
</listener>
```